# cakephp print a boolean

Tags: cakephp, boolean

Beginners question in cakePHP, it drives me mad, I tried so much but can't get this working in cakePHP.
I want to print 'Train station nearby' if the boolean is set.
The database has the field 'train' bit(1) when doing a

```
<?php echo h($property['Property']['train']); ?>
```

it shows 1 but in the database it is 0, WHY is it printing 1 instead of 0

```
<?php if($property['Property']['train'] == true ) echo 'Train station nearby'; ?>
```

This output works all the time, but of course it is not true!
Anyone please, is this something to do with the fact it is a bit(1) field or am I doing something wrong. Please keep in mind I am a beginner, and I did try a lot of php examples with booleans, but just can't work out why it is not working for me in cakePHP.
Thanks for looking into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using mysql use `tinyint(1)` for the field which is emulated as boolean.

Comment: That means I need to convert the field, can this be done without any negative effects?

Comment: THANKS, after converting field to tinyint(1) it works, yippee :-))

Answer (score 0):

According to this [ticket](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/2028) bit type fields are currently not supported by CakePHP. Instead, use the [`boolean`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html) type for boolean values.

Comment: The DB is a mssql and it seems with M$ it is no problem, but indeed different with MySQL :-(

Comment: Sorry converted from mssql to mysql. but that is no problem i understand it is cakePHP which cant handle this [yet]