# CakePHP - Fetching data, checking against TRUE/FALSE

Tags: mysql, cakephp, bit

In my database, my table has the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_app_versions` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `app` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `version` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `force_update` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_active` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Note that 'force_update' is bit. It can be either 1 or 0.

In my code, I fetch the data and want to see if the value is 1 or 0. CakePHP for some reason returns the following in either case:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Platforms] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [app] => ios
                    [version] => 1.0.042
                    [force_update] => 
                    [is_active] => 
                    [created] => 
                    [modified] => 
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Platforms] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [app] => android
                    [version] => 1.0.041
                    [force_update] => 
                    [is_active] => 
                    [created] => 
                    [modified] => 
                )
        )
)
```

Regardless of it's value, force_update shows the same. I'm using bit in most of my tables and I have to be able to do this check.

This:

```
<?php echo ($value['Platforms']['force_update']) ? 'Yes' : 'No'; ?>
```

Or:

```
<?php echo ($value['Platforms']['force_update'] = TRUE) ? 'Yes' : 'No'; ?>
```

Or:

```
<?php echo ($value['Platforms']['force_update'] == TRUE) ? 'Yes' : 'No'; ?>
```

all result in the same despite the fact that my data is:

```
'1', 'ios', '1.0.042', '0', '1', NULL, NULL
'2', 'android', '1.0.041', '1', '1', NULL, NULL
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [cakephp print a boolean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15868828/cakephp-print-a-boolean)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using bit in database, if field is NULL, it returns FALSE, otherwise it returns TRUE.

So if it has any value in the field (1 or 0) it still returns TRUE.

Solution:
Change the field from bit to tinyint.
OR
On data manipulation, NULL the field in terms of FALSE and give it a value in terms of TRUE. This way every time I read the data it's either NULL or has a value, then based on that I can show the proper message in the views.

Answer (score 0):

You could switch from bit to tinyint (1) but I think your if statement is wrong.

Try

```
<?php echo (!empty($value['Platforms']['force_update'])) ? 'Yes' : 'No'; ?>
```

empty() will catch botch NULL and 0 as 'No' and only 1 as 'yes'.